# Memory-efficient DataFrame.stack()

Tags: python, pandas, memory

If I `memray` the following code, `df.stack()` allocates 22MB, when the df is only 5MB.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

columns = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000, 26*26)), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([columns, columns]))
print(df.memory_usage().sum()) # 5408128, ~5MB
df.stack() # reshape: (1000,26*26) -> (1000*26,26)
```

Why DataFrame.stack() consumes so much memory? It allocates 30% on dropna and remaining 70% re-allocating the underlying array 3 times to reshape. Shall I move to native `numpy.reshape` or is there anything I can do to make it slimmer?

Comment: why do you perform a `stack`? how you are going to use this stacked dataframe after?

Comment: It is meaningful from a data perspective, i.e. it is a timeseries of square matrices - in this case it is an API requirement shape=(Mutilindex(time,columns), columns). I agree that the unstack, flatten version with 26*26 cols is computationally handier